# What is the proper name for this "tersest path" problem in Infinite Craft?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, combinatorial-optimization

The web game [*Infinite Craft*](https://neal.fun/infinite-craft/) gives you a starting set of elements $V_0\subset V$ and a mapping $E$ of type $V\times V\rightarrow V$. In fact, $F$ is commutative: $E(v_a,v_b) = E(v_b,v_a)$. So another way to describe this structure is as a [directed hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) on $V$ where every edge is of the form $(\{v_a,v_b\}, \{v_c\})$.

I'm looking for information on how to find "tersest routes" in this structure. However, our definition of "route" is different from the usual mathematical definition of a "path" in a hypergraph. Let a "route" in *Infinite Craft* be a sequence $v_{1..n}$ such that for each $i$, either $v_i\in V_0$ or else $v_i = E(v_g, v_h)$ for some $g,h < i$.

For example, one route from $V_0= \{\text{Earth},\text{Wind},\text{Fire},\text{Water}\}$ to $\text{Sandwich}$ is six steps:

```
Wave = Water + Wind
Steam = Fire + Water
Plant = Earth + Water
Sand = Earth + Wave
Tea = Plant + Steam
Sandwich = Sand + Tea
```

But the *tersest* route from $V_0= \{\text{Earth},\text{Wind},\text{Fire},\text{Water}\}$ to $\text{Sandwich}$ is only five steps:

```
Wave = Water + Wind
Sand = Earth + Wave
Glass = Fire + Sand
Wine = Glass + Water
Sandwich = Sand + Wine
```

That route involves $\text{Wine}$, and gets to $\text{Wine}$ in the fourth step. But the *tersest* route from $V_0= \{\text{Earth},\text{Wind},\text{Fire},\text{Water}\}$ to $\text{Wine}$ is only three steps:

```
Plant = Earth + Water
Dandelion = Plant + Wind
Wine = Dandelion + Water
```

which isn't a subset of the tersest route to $\text{Sandwich}$!

This seems to make it really computationally expensive to compute tersest routes from $V_0$ to $v_\text{target}$. I'm looking for resources on this structure — what is it called (besides being a very specific shape of "hypergraph")? Has it been studied before? What is the proper name for this sort of "route" (or perhaps "support"), which is different from an ordinary linear "path"? Surely something like *this* must have been studied before (perhaps in the context of job-scheduling theory)? Are there any route-finding algorithms analogous to [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) on this kind of structure?

Comment: Finding [addition chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain?wprov=sfla1) is a particular instance of this task which is quite hard, so it's likely there aren't any efficient algorithms.

Comment: @CommandMaster: Ah, that's very interesting! IIUC, $V=\mathbb{Z}, E=+, V_0=\{0\}$ is a (unsurprisingly) well-studied and (very surprisingly to me) _non-trivial_ example of the exact algebraic structure I'm talking about! I'm still in the dark as to the proper name _for_ this kind of algebraic structure, though.

Comment: That is *shortest hyperpath problem* (ref: [Directed hypergraphs: Introduction and fundamental algorithms—A survey](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397516002097)) but I couldn't find any articles from a practical standpoint.

Comment: I think you can view these paths as proofs in linear logic (which is a good match for this kind of problem as it can model resources) so maybe check out the linear logic proof search literature. Eg. see discussion of vending machines here: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=93e8947f201532eebd94e9f7fc3d90e5326911e4

Answer (score 0):

The kind of hypergraphs you describe are a special case of hypergraphs where
edges are *ordered lists* of nodes, e.g.

```
$e = ([ v_a, v_b ], [v_c])$
```

"Routes" in this kind of hypergraph correspond to morphisms of symmetric
monoidal categories - [here is a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.01847.pdf)
which describes this correspondence.

More precisely, what you have is essentially a *presentation of a symmetric
monoidal category*:

- Some generating objects $\Sigma_0 = \{ \mathsf{Earth}, \mathsf{Wind}, ... \}$
- For each production rule like `Wave = Water + Wind`, a generating operation
  $f : Water \otimes Wind → Wave$

Your category then has objects $\Sigma_0$ plus their tensor products (e.g.,
$\mathsf{Earth} \otimes \mathsf{Wind} \otimes \ldots$).
Morphisms in this category correspond to your "routes"; routes go between a
starting list of "resources" to a resulting list of resources.

There is one piece missing; we require each $f : A \otimes B \to C$ to be
commutative, so we actually have a symmetric monoidal *theory* with an equation
$\sigma ; f = f$ for each operation $f$.

There is some work on studying "route-finding" algorithms in this context, but
I'm not intimately familiar with it. Here are some pointers:

- [A Categorical Representation Language and Computational System for
  Knowledge-Based Planning](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.17208)
- [Open Algebraic Path problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.06682.pdf)
- [Structured Decompositions: Structural and Algorithmic Compositionality](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.06091.pdf)
- [Monoidal Width](https://lmcs.episciences.org/12379)
- [String Diagrams for Assembly Planning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.10475.pdf)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (likely!), I feel like symmetric monoidal categories don't really apply here because there's no guarantee of associativity, so it seems like $\mathsf{Earth}\otimes\mathsf{Wind}\otimes\mathsf{Water}$, for instance, isn't well-defined because you have no guarantee that there's an isomorphism between $(\mathsf{Earth}\otimes\mathsf{Wind})\otimes\mathsf{Water}$ and $\mathsf{Earth}\otimes(\mathsf{Wind}\otimes\mathsf{Water})$.

Comment: Ah, I'm assuming strictness which is required for the correspondence to the kind of hypergraphs I described. But I guess you also want commutativity of objects, so that $\mathsf{Earth} \otimes \mathsf{Water} \cong \mathsf{Water} \otimes \mathsf{Earth}$. I'm pretty sure this is still just a special case of strict SMCs though.

Answer (score 0):

I am embarrassed not to have recognized this sooner, but a 'canonical' structure that models Infinite Craft is the [Commutative Magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_magma) — definitionally, a set $S$ with a binary operation $\oplus$ that is closed ($s\oplus t$ is defined and is $\in S$ for all $s,t\in S$) and commutative. Unfortunately, the level of generality at play here means that this is not necessarily helpful for practical considerations, but those are the magic words I'd start with to try and find more information if it's out there.

Note that breadth-first search provides an algorithm polynomial time in the size $\sigma=|S|$ of the magma: let $S_0$ be your chosen generating set and $S_{n+1}=S_n\cup(S_n\oplus S_n)$. Then if $S_{n+1}=S_n$ then clearly $S_m=S_n$ for all $m\geq n$; otherwise, at least one element must be added at every stage, so after at most $\sigma$ stages we must either get $S$ or hit a fixed-point. Either way, $S_\mu=S_\sigma$ for all $\mu\geq\sigma$. This gives an $O(\sigma^3)$ algorithm, since computing each stage $S_{n+1}$ takes $O(|S_n|^2)\subseteq O(\sigma^2)$ time.